# how to set an absolute path in gradle for tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I have a basic task like this

```
task copy-Library(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/outputs/aar/app-debug_-debug.aar'
    into "D:\\root\\path\\to\\directory\\Plugins\\Android"
    rename { String fileName ->
        fileName.replace("app-debug_-debug.aar", "myLibray-debug.aar")
    }
}
```

it works fine

but I'd like to put the path `"D:\\root\\path\\to\\directory\\Plugins\\Android"` into some variable so i could call from other tasks

`into myPath`

I'm guessing that my gradle task would end something like this

```
\\ set the path variable
how.do.I.set myPath = "D:\\root\\path\\to\\directory\\Plugins\\Android"

task copy-Library(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/outputs/aar/app-debug_-debug.aar'
    into myPath
    rename { String fileName ->
        fileName.replace("app-debug_-debug.aar", "myLibray-debug.aar")
    }
}
```

such that I might add another task that uses that same path?

```
task deleteLibrary(type: Delete){
    delete fileTree(myPath) {
        include '**/*.ext'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `def` is what you want:

```
def myPath  = "D:\\root\\path\\to\\directory\\Plugins\\Android" //define variable myPath 



task copy-Library(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/outputs/aar/app-debug_-debug.aar'
    into myPath   //"$myPath" also should work
    rename { String fileName ->
        fileName.replace("app-debug_-debug.aar", "myLibray-debug.aar")
    }
}

task deleteLibrary(type: Delete){
    delete fileTree($myPath) {
        include '**/*.ext'
    }
}
```

See [writing_build_scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html)

Comment: Yes, def is what I was looking for. Thanks. And thanks for the link.